# Slick-slider внутри собственного макета балуна в мобилке не отрабатывает

Tags: яндекс-карты

Внедрил яндекс карты на сайт. Сделал свой макет шаблона Балуна, прописал в build код слайдера. Для ПК версии всё работает, но в мобильной версии Балун открывается снизу карты и не инициализируется slick-slider для него. Как сделать рабочим в мобилке?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не сказали, что нужно - балун оставить на мобилке или на панель добавить тоже Slick-slider? Панель вообще можно отключить через https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon.html А в целом лучше минимальный пример прикрепите. ...на том же https://jsbin.com/

Comment: @YaCor', добавить в панель инициализацию slick-slider

Comment: Понятно. Тогда отключать панель не вариант. А минимальный пример в какой-нибудь песочнице можете собрать? По идее в панели тоже должно работать. Хотелось бы увидеть проблему живьём.